# Expressing polynomial as sum of 2 squares.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got the following question.

Given the following:

$4n+1=x^2+y^2$     and  $ n=((a^2+a)/2)+(b^2+b)/2)$

I've been asked to express "x" and "y" in terms of "a" and "b" . But I  just can't get it right, I always end up with something in terms of "x" or "y".

I got to this point and can't seem to get further on my own:

$2a^2+2b^2+2a+2b+1=x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... you just have to make the algebraic observation / guess

> $2a^2 + 2b^2 + 2a + 2b + 1 = (a+b+1)^2 + (a-b)^2$

---

Another possible expression is

> $( \sqrt{2} a + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} ) ^2 + ( \sqrt{2} b + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} ) ^2$

---

Based on the coefficients, good first guess are

> $a \pm b, a \pm b \pm 1$.

We are lucky that these worked.
Otherwise, w could have tried

> $\alpha a \pm \beta b$

Comment: Thank you for you insight. If there any way to know which part corresponds to "x" or "y" or we can just express it as: $x=a+b+1$ and $y=a-b$ or viceversa.

Comment: No way to know which part, since it's interchangable. You can write it as $ \{ x, y \} = \{ a +b+1, a-b\}$. Of course, note that this expression need not b unique.

Comment: Perfect! Can't seem to grasp why the  expression is not unique.Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Just saw what you meant!  Thanks for elaborating.